# Selecting matrices based on existence of unique column and row of all equal terms

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

So, I have a list of lists of lists such as the following:

```
{{{4}},
{{7, 7}, {7, 7}},
{{5, 5}, {6, 6}},
{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}}
```

Interpreting the elements of this list as $n\times n$ matrices, I want to iterate through and select matrices where exactly one column and one row consist only of a particular element which only occurs in that column or row.

So, building from the example above, `{{4}}` would be selected as there is only one column or row to consider. `{{7, 7}, {7, 7}}` would not be selected as, while there is a column and row that each contain only 7, there is also a 7 not contained in that column or row.`{{5, 5}, {6, 6}}` would not be selected because, while there are rows that fit our requirement, there are no columns. `{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}` would be selected as it satisfies all requirements.

What are some ways that you could put together a function to identify these matrices?

Comment: "Interpreting the elements of this list as n x n matrices" Well, you can't. Three of the elements are 2 x 2 matices but the 1st isn't a 2 x 2 matrix or an n x n matrix for any other `n`, so the whole idea collapses.

Comment: Ah, that's just a 1x1 matrix. Arguably there are no meaningful difference between a 1x1 matrix and a single element, but that doesn't mean you can't still consider it a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]
f1 = Cases[{___, {Except[a_]..., a_, Except[a_]...}, ___}]@*Cases[{___, {(a_)..}, ___}];
f2 = Select[MemberQ[Tally /@ #, {_, 1}, All] &]@*Cases[{___, {(a_)..}, ___}] ;
f3 = Pick[#, MemberQ[#, {_, 1}, All]& /@ Map[Tally, #, {2}]]& @*Cases[{___, {(a_)..}, ___}];
```

**Examples:**

```
lst1 = {{{4}}, {{7, 7}, {7, 7}}, {{5, 5}, {6, 6}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 1}}};
f1 @ lst1
```

> {{{4}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 1}}}

```
f1 @ lst1 == f2 @ lst1 == f3 @lst1
```

> True

```
lst2 = {{{3, 3}, {3, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 
     0}, {1, 0, 3, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 0, 4}, {1, 3, 3, 
     3, 0}, {1, 0, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 4, 0, 4, 4}}} ;
f1 @ lst2 == f2 @lst2 == f3 @ lst2 == lst2
```

> True

Comment: Thank you for the different versions. This gives me a lot of stuff to read up on.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{{4}}, {{7, 7}, {7, 7}}, {{5, 5}, {6, 6}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 1}}}    

Select[list,Length[s=Select[#,Length@Union@#==1&]]==1&&Equal[s&/@{#,Transpose@#}]&@#&]
```

> {{{4}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 1}}}

Comment: Running this returns only 1x1 or 2x2 matrices. What if the list of matrices contain larger matrices, such as 4x4 or 5x5?

Comment: @Rithaniel Did you try it with larger matrices and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes, with: 
{{{3, 3}, {3, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 3, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 0, 4}, {1, 3, 3, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 4, 0, 4, 4}}}
it returned: 
{{{3, 3}, {3, 2}}}

Comment: @Rithaniel and? what is the right answer?

Comment: In that particular situation the correct answer should be the entire input. In both the 4x4 and 5x5 case, the first row and first column are all 1s and 1 is only present in that row/column.

Comment: I believe that now it works

Comment: Indeed it does. Thank you for the help.